# Serial COMM port in windows remains owned after closing

Tags: java, serial-port

I have a problem with comm ports in JAVA.
I'm using Java version, 1.5 because that version still have access to windows COMM ports (serials).

The problem is that the command throws the exception:

```
javax.comm.PortInUseException: Port currently owned by Unknown Windows Application
```

The thing is that the application opens the comm port for the first time, then I close the comm when the user exits some window.
But the user may return to that window, and therefore I try to open again the same port:

I close with:

```
if (puertoSerie != null) {
 puertoSerie.removeEventListener();
puertoSerie.close();
puertoSerie = null;
}
```

So I added a `PortOwnershipListener`:

```
idPuerto.addPortOwnershipListener(new MyResolver());
```

And the error says:

```
Somebody else has the port
Somebody else has the port
```

That occurs when :

```
case PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED:
if (owned) {
System.out.println("Owned ... Somebody else has the port");
} else {
System.out.println("Somebody else has the port");
}
```

Any Idea how to work around this?
Best Regards

Comment: did you check with netstat -an | find ":PORT", if your application still listening port after you trying to close?

Comment: Hi, I found that the isse only happenps when I uses USB-to-Serial adapter, even more, if I unplug and plug ths adapter, before second comm port open cycle, it looks like works fine. But I'm curious about how to solve this, without unplugin ! Best Regards

Comment: +HRgiger , i'm on windows, I think I can't nestat that info !

Comment: sorry I had in my win, maybe I have installed before, anyway seems like I mixed with network ports :) Happy you found

Answer (score 0):

The new java JDK 1.7 also has serial port programming using the `java.comm` and `rxtx` api's.

You can install them and run them if you like and you can use `serialPort.close();`  to end the connection.